# Rails checkbox array choose nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, has-and-belongs-to-many

I m getting the computer_ids of user like that

```
<%= check_box_tag "user[computer_ids][]", computer.id, @user.computers.include?(computer) %>
```

If I choose at least one from checkbox array, that's fine. But if I did not choose any thing it give me an array like that

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

That's because there is no parameter comes. I did not find a solution. The relation is habtm

I'm try to control it is empty or not

```
if ( !(params[:user][:computer_ids].empty?)  )
```

**EDIT:**

since computer_ids is the only parameter in users
it didn't understand what params[:user] is and that's why it gives an error.

```
if ( !(params[:user].present?)  ) , has solved the problem
```

Comment: `if params[:user][:computer_ids].present?` this condition will solve your problem

Comment: did not change any thing

Answer (score 1):

Add hidden field above all check-boxes with empty value. It will be sent in case user didn't check any check-boxes like:-

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "user[computer_ids][]", nil %>
    <% Computer.all.each do |computer| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "user[computer_ids][]", computer.id, @user.computers.include?(computer) %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit'%>
<% end %>
```

Reject blank values from params like:-

```
params[:user][:computer_ids] = params[:user][:computer_ids].reject { |c| c.empty? }
```

Comment: I think you mean `<%= hidden_field_tag "user[computer_ids][]", nil %>`

Comment: `"user"=>{"computer_ids"=>["", "1"]}`, the empty one give me a problem